# How do I access and hide markers created by loadGeoJson()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am loading custom coordinates into my map application via JSON. I have been able to find out how to color code the markers based on feature properties, but one of my next steps will be to create filters to show or hide markers based on the properties.

My code starts like this:

```
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize()
{
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    map.data.loadGeoJson('/map_json.php', null, SetBounds);

    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        var color = 'FF0000';
        var symbol = '%E2%80%A2';  // dot
        // color selection code here [...]

        return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ {
            icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=' + symbol + '|' + color
        };
}
```

I already found how I can access the imported data through a jquery autocomplete search:

```
$(input).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        data = [];
        map.data.forEach(function(feature)
        {
            var str = request.term.toUpperCase();
            if (String(feature.getProperty('name')).toUpperCase().indexOf(str) > -1)
            {
                data.push({id: feature.getProperty('id'), name: feature.getProperty('name'), address: feature.getProperty('address')});
            }
        });
        response(data);
    },
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        map.data.forEach(function(feature)
        {
            if (feature.getProperty('id') == ui.item.id)
            {
                var content = GetContent(feature);
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.setPosition(feature.getGeometry().get());
                infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -34)});
                infowindow.open(map);

                // zoom in
                map.setZoom(15);
                map.panTo(feature.getGeometry().get());

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
})
.autocomplete().data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item)
{
    return $('<li>')
        .append('<a>' + item.name + ' (ID: ' + item.id + ')<br>' + item.address + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul)
};
```

So using this same principle to run my filters is not a problem.

The problem is that I have not found a way yet to access the visible markers based on the `feature` information that I have in `map.data`.

All the examples I found so far are based on the principle of manually adding markers and storing them in an array to access later, e.g.:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

But I don't have that - I load the entire set of data using `getGeoJson()`.

How can I access the marker and manipulate it (e.g. hide it or show it) based on the information I can access using `map.data.forEach()`?

--- Update ---

Here are more details on the project.

The map will markers that are generated from a list of customers. The customers have different categories and properties, so a typical entry form the GeoJSON string would look like this:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0,0]},"properties":{"name":"Customer 1","id":"1001","address":"1234 Test Street, Test City, TX 12345, USA","category":"vendor","active":1}}
```

Also on the map is a filter box with checkboxes that are checked by default. Clicking any of them will run the filtering code that should hide or remove the markers that are associated with any customers that match that filter.

So if I disable the checkbox that filters "inactive", then only customers with the property `"active":1` will remain on the map. If I disable the checkbox that filters "vendors", then all customers with the category "vendor" will be hidden.

Checking the checkboxes again later will undo the hiding of these entries.

What I have found in my research is a lot of mentioning of markers, but ONLY if they are added manually - not via GeoJSON import.

I can see a few potential solutions to my problem - I could ignore the GeoJSON format and instead import the client list into jQuery manually and parse it from there into markers that then go into an array. But then why use the GeoJSON format at all?

My current solution of using `map.data.setStyle()` (see comment) seems to work and do the job. But I am curious if there isn't another more direct way.

I figured, the filter function would go through all data (`map.data.forEach()`) to locate any items that should be hidden based on the filters, and then each item would communicate to its associated marker that the marker needs to be hidden. But it is this association that I have not been able to figure out so far.

When I loop through all features (`map.data.forEach()`), I have access to the data I uploaded, but not to the markers that were placed as a result of the import.

My question is if there is a direct way to access the marker from the feature.

I hope this is clearer now.

--- Update ---

I created a very simple jsfiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/semmelbroesel/9bv68ngp/

This is the concept I want to achieve, and it works as is. My only question is if there is another way to achieve the same results by directly accessing the placed markers instead of using `setStyle()` to hide/show them.

Comment: FYI, I've researched this for days now and haven't found a way to connect the two concepts - I think I deserve at least to be told why within 5 minutes  of posting I got a -1...

Comment: I found a temporary solution that will do what I need for now by setting the style of markers. Maybe this is the only way of doing this...

`map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
      if (feature.getProperty('active') != 1)
      {
        return {visible: false};
      }
      else
      {
        return null;  // will be changed to preserving the original format
      }
    });`

If I don't get any other answers over the weekend, I'll use this as the answer and close the question.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what your code does and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @geocodezip I would, but my main issue is that I am using `loadGeoJson()` which requires an external url that I can't implement into jsFiddle directly unless I store that file somewhere public... I will add more details to my original post, though.

Comment: You can use the addGeoJson method to load a simple test version of your data.

Comment: I could, but it's private data that I can't make public... I included a sample of the file structure in the details. I'll have to go now and will check again on Monday.

Comment: I suggested a "simple test version of your data", doesn't need to be real data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `forEach`, since `setStyle` does already traverse the Features.

If you declare the styling function as:

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var color = 'FF0000';
    var symbol = '%E2%80%A2';  // dot

    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */ {
        visible: feature.getProperty('active'), // this links visibility to feature property
        icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=' + symbol + '|' + color
    };
});
```

You don't need to call the method again, since the style gets bound to the feature property. Setting the `active` property to false will propagate to the marker style seamlessly.

After that, you can make your filters like (rough example)

```
var setFilter = function(property, value) {
    map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
        feature.setProperty('active', feature.getProperty(property) === value);
    });
};
```

and calling for example `setFilter('name','John');`

Again, this is a rough example. I'd rather implement the filtering method on the `google.maps.Data` prototype, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: So your approach is also to go from `google.maps.Data` to `setStyle()` like I ended up doing. I like your concept of making the style dependent on the feature's property - will that update automatically when the property is changed? If yes, then I think that'll work really well for me!

Comment: It's not really my approach. Opposite from the concept of manually instancing separate overlays (markers, polylines, polygons, etc), the data layer provides an iterator for its underlying data, but each element of that data isn't a visible overlay by itself, just an abstract structure that happens to be a Feature. The visible part resides in the data layer as an aggregate concept.